# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11:49:28 முற்பகல்"

Tags: java, android

If tamil language is selected in android date, the  `AM` should look like `"முற்பகல்"`.
For that how will parse the date?

```
com.carepredict.cp_native W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11:49:28 முற்பகல்" (at offset 9)
02-20 17:19:28.310 22978-22978/com.carepredict.cp_native W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
        at com.carepredict.cp_native.holders.AlertListitemHolder.bindFloors(AlertListitemHolder.java:173)
        at com.carepredict.cp_native.adapters.AlertListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlertListAdapter.java:41)
        at com.carepredict.cp_native.adapters.AlertListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlertListAdapter.java:15)
```

Comment: you can string replace "முற்பகல்” as am then parse the  value

Comment: without doing that any option for automatic handle

Comment: You should add the code that produces the error.

Comment: java supports default format only ..custom language  you have to customize the values..otherwise no option

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = sdf.parse(strAlertStartTime);

Comment: ok. thank u @sasikumar

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `replace` function which will help

use like this

```
String date = ("11:49:28 முற்பகல்").replace("முற்பகல்", "am");
String date1 = ("11:49:28 பிற்பகல்").replace("பிற்பகல்", "pm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
String myDateString = "13:24:40 முற்பகல்";
String[] splitT       = myDateString.split(" ");

LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(splitT[0], 
                      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));

int hour = localTime.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = localTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
int second = localTime.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
```

> You can again add it to the string whatever you want.. like

**splitT [0] is this value "13:24:40" and splitT[1] will have your special string i.e , "முற்பகல்"**

```
  desiredString = str + splitT[1];
```

**Edit** :- to assign the correct **vernacular language** for time **(hours of the day am or pm)** in this case its Tamil so... do this checking..

```
if (hour >=12)
      {
         desiredString = str + "பிற்பகல்"  ;// for **pm**

         }
    else 
      {
         desiredString = str + "முற்பகல்"; // for  **am**


        }
```

Comment: if 13:24:40 is the time means no issue with "முற்பகல்"(AM) or "PM". Because we know it is after 1 o'clk.  It is "01:24:40" means we dont know either it forenoon or afternoon. In English no problem for parsing in JAVA. If tamil selected means we can get the string like "01:24:40 முற்பகல்". So, what can we do now ?

Comment: முற்பகல் - am,    பிற்பகல் - pm

Comment: yes. but if the time string is 13:24:40 means we can check whether it is greater or less than 12. if  "01:24:40 முற்பகல்" means ?